# ZF2 - database and models

Tags: zend-framework2

I followed this examples http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html to create a model and a way to save it to a database.

But I don't like the idea of using the `AlubumTable`-class in my controller as I think this creates too much dependencies. I just want to add the `save()`, `fetchAll()`, etc. methods to my model so that I don't have to care about how to save my models inside my controller.

If I want to change the way my models get stored e.g. from a database to a REST-service I would have to rewrite every part of my controller where I get or store models instead of just changing the `save()` etc. methods in my model.

Are there any tutorials for my way or is this just a stupid idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

The concern you have is actually OK, but you have to realize that the `AlbumTable` is nothing but a layer between your Controller and the Database. The `AlbumTable` actually is the one thing with the dependency, not the controller.

The Controller will always need some sort of "Service" or "Gateway" (which would be `AlbumTable`) to get access to the Data from the DB.

Also i do not understand what you mean by "i want to change the way my models get stored" - You should always store the MODEL into your Service. In the given example the Model is `Album` and the Service is `AlbumTable`. No matter where the data comes from - REST, RPC, "normal HTTP", you would always store the Album and not some ArrayData or whatnot. You'd rather try to implement a function inside your model like `exchangeArray()`, `exchangeJson()`.

You may want to make your "problem" more clear to us...

Comment: Ok, the model needs to be stored or retrieved in some way. And I like the idea that the model is completely responsible for the way this is done. Inside my controller I just want to call `Album::fetchAll()` and get all `Album`s and I don't want to think about whether a database or some other service gets called to do this. I dont' want to instantiate `AlbumTable` when using a database or - lets say - `AlbumRest` when using a REST-Service. Does this clarify my problem?